# Android Resource linking failed in AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, linker, resources

ERROR:C:\Users\Apochi\IgClone\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.InstagramCloneApp (aka com.example.instagramcloneapp:style/Theme.InstagramCloneApp) not found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As error suggest your app theme does not exist, style/Theme.InstagramCloneApp (aka com.example.instagramcloneapp:style/Theme.InstagramCloneApp) not found.